# Am I able to access the current song playing on SiriusXM?

Tags: python

I contacted support for SiriusXM about favoriting songs and getting a notification if one pops up, and they said it was a feature only available for car radios. So I was thinking I could make my own program, but I can't find any information on accessing the 'Now Playing' data, so if anyone here could help me, that would be wonderful :)

Comment: Not sure if this is possible but this documentation might help if you're trying to use their API. https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/siriusxm/latest/siriusxm.pdf

Comment: Appears to be on page 14 of the Python API referenced by @KyIeLiebIer above.